# Alter all webform fields

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

If we want to alter webform item e.g. add a colon `:` to a label of a specific field, we use this:

`$form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] = $form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] . ":";`

But what if we want to apply that colon to all field labels and not just that one `my_form_component`?

Current code:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){
  if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_client_form_') === 0) {
    $form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] = $form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] . ":";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a recursive function, looping through the render array and adding a colon to any elements that have a #title element.

```php
function addColonsToTitles(&$element) {
  if (isset($element['#title'])) {
    $element['#title'] .= ':';
  }

  foreach (element_children($element) as $index) {
    addColonsToTitles($element[$index]);
  }
}

function MYTHEME_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){
  if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_client_form_') === 0) {
    addColonsToTitles($form['submitted']);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves it, but I also expected for the colons to appear in emails. They actually appear by default, but toggling HTML setting for emails in Webforms for some reason strips colons. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You asked how to change form labels. The labels in the email will not be form labels, and the manner of adding colons would be entirely different. You can open a new issue for that.